# Output a total that will be used for further computation - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, calculator

how can I add the inputted data under 'unit cost', 'finance %' and 'freight cost/unit' and output that in 'unit landed cost price'? Here's a screenshot to illustrate http://s18.postimg.org/b1avx0omx/retail_calc.png

Here's the current script supplied.

```
<script>
    var gstPercent = 10.0;

    function retailToolkit_UpdateRetailCalculator()
    {
        var sellPrice = retailToolkit_ValidateFloatInput('txtRetailCalculatorSellPrice');
        var costPrice = retailToolkit_ValidateFloatInput('txtRetailCalculatorCostPrice');
        var margin = retailToolkit_ValidateFloatInput('txtRetailCalculatorMargin');
        var grossMargin = retailToolkit_ValidateFloatInput('txtRetailCalculatorGrossMargin');
        var inputCount = 0;
        if (!isNaN(sellPrice))
            inputCount++;
        if (!isNaN(costPrice))
            inputCount++;
        if (!isNaN(margin))
            inputCount++;
        if (!isNaN(grossMargin))
            inputCount++;
        if (inputCount == 2)
        {
            var sellPriceExGST;
            if (isNaN(sellPrice))
            {
                if (isNaN(costPrice))
                {
                    //we have margin & grossMargin
                    sellPriceExGST = grossMargin / (margin / 100.0);
                    costPrice = sellPriceExGST - grossMargin;
                    sellPrice = sellPriceExGST + (sellPriceExGST * (gstPercent / 100));
                }
                else if (isNaN(margin))
                {
                    //we have costPrice & grossMargin
                    sellPriceExGST = costPrice + grossMargin
                    sellPrice = sellPriceExGST + (sellPriceExGST * (gstPercent / 100));
                }
                else
                {
                    //we have costPrice & margin
                    sellPriceExGST = (costPrice / (100 - margin)) * 100;
                    sellPrice = sellPriceExGST + (sellPriceExGST * (gstPercent / 100));
                }
            }
            else
                sellPriceExGST = (sellPrice / (100 + gstPercent)) * 100;
            //once we reach here we now definitely have sellPriceExGST & sellPrice
            if (isNaN(costPrice))
            {
                if (!isNaN(grossMargin))                                //we have sellPriceExGST & grossMargin
                    costPrice = sellPriceExGST - grossMargin;
                else
                {
                    //we have sellPriceExGST & margin
                    grossMargin = sellPriceExGST * margin / 100;
                    costPrice = sellPriceExGST - grossMargin;
                }
            }
            if (isNaN(grossMargin))
                grossMargin = sellPriceExGST - costPrice;
            if (isNaN(margin))
                margin = (grossMargin / sellPriceExGST) * 100;
            document.getElementById("spanRetailCalculatorSellPrice").innerHTML = FormatCost(sellPrice, "$", 2);
            document.getElementById("spanRetailCalculatorCostPrice").innerHTML = FormatCost(costPrice, "$", 2);
            document.getElementById("spanRetailCalculatorMargin").innerHTML = FormatCost(margin, "", 1) + "%";
            document.getElementById("spanRetailCalculatorGrossMargin").innerHTML = FormatCost(grossMargin, "$", 2);
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("spanRetailCalculatorSellPrice").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("spanRetailCalculatorCostPrice").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("spanRetailCalculatorMargin").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("spanRetailCalculatorGrossMargin").innerHTML = "";
        }
    }

    function retailToolkit_ValidateFloatInput(inputCtrlId)
    {
        var ctrl = document.getElementById(inputCtrlId);
        var flt = parseFloat(ctrl.value);
        if (isNaN(flt))
            ctrl.value = '';
        else
        {
            var corrected = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < ctrl.value.length; i++)
            {
                if ((ctrl.value[i] >= '0' && ctrl.value[i] <= '9') || ctrl.value[i] == '.')
                    corrected += ctrl.value[i];
            }
            ctrl.value = corrected;
        }
        return flt;
    }
</script>`
```

and the HTML is below.

```
            <tr>
                <td>Unit Landed Cost Price (excluding GST), including finance and freight charges</td>
                <td>$</td>
                <td><span id="spanRetailCalculatorCostPrice"></span><br />
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
              <table>
              <tr>
              <td>Unit Cost</td>
              <td>Finance %</td>
              <td>Freight Cost/Unit</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td><input type="text" onkeyup="return retailToolkit_UpdateRetailCalculator()" id="txtRetailCalculatorCostPrice" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" onkeyup="return retailToolkit_UpdateRetailCalculator()" id="txtRetailCalculatorFinancePercentage" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" onkeyup="return retailToolkit_UpdateRetailCalculator()" id="txtRetailCalculatorFreightCost" /></td>
              </tr>
              </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
```

Comment: Lots of code. Please narrow it down if you can.

Comment: The code shown already demonstrates methods of retrieving values from fields, performing maths operations on those values, and displaying the results. Where are you getting stuck in trying to do the same for the unit cost, etc, fields?

Comment: As others have said, you need to trim this example down to the minimum amount of HTML and JS that represents the problem.

Comment: I don't know what to cut :|

Comment: @nnnnnn I don't have a function to output the total of those three fields. I need to output a total of those three, then be able to use that (by ID I assume?) to process the rest of the function. More of an HTML CSS guy but understands a bit of JS (self-thought) but having nested else ifs is a trouble to me.